# Eclipse editors (text, html, javascript...) open with nothing displayed

Tags: eclipse, fonts, color-scheme

After installing updates yesterday to some Eclipse components, opening files (.js, .java, .html...) in Eclipse editors would show the edit tab and the scroll bar but nothing appeared. Select all, copy and pasting elsewhere showed the content so it was there so I assumed this was a white font on a white background (though none of the color highlighting was present either). Eclipse Colors and Fonts settings showed the Consolas font as a choice, but some of the choices for editing in Eclipse Colors and Fonts showed the icon but no text describing what the setting was, nor was the preview showing anything. Changing to Courier New as a test fixed the problem but switching back to Consolas showed no content in the editors (white on white background)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some head scratching, I found something had happened to the Consolas font that was installed but was showing nothing. Though it showed as a choice in Eclipse Colors and Fonts, it was not showing in the Windows Font choices... I had to reinstall the Consolas font to fix the problem. I hope this helps others with a similar problem.